# Python build doesn't work on Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Whenever I build (<kbd>Cmd+B</kbd>) on Sublime Text 3 it doesn't execute my code.

I used <kbd>Shift+Command+B</kbd> to set the build system to Python. I also tried making my own build system by using the `which python3.6` command in terminal, which said `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6`

I put in this in my custom build system

```json
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

However I still get the same error. Please help.

[image: This is what I get when I try to build]

I know this is a really stupid question, I'm sure I just have to change some settings to solve this, thanks for you time.

Comment: The build system in your question doesn't specify the Python that you said you found; however @varunsangal is correct; you need to save the file before the external Python interpreter can run it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Python can't find anything to build.

A couple of quick things:

1. You don't seem to have saved your file. Save it with a .py extention.
2. Is Python on your path? Try to type  " python " in a cmd terminal.

Comment: Python is definitely in the path because it's the Python interpreter that's displaying the error. You're correct that the issue is that the file hasn't been saved.

Answer (score 0):

For sublime text, it's better to use package: Anaconda.

Here is a [blog](https://hanbaobao2005.wordpress.com/2016/06/07/python%E5%A4%9A%E7%89%88%E6%9C%AC-sublime-text-anaconda%E6%8C%87%E5%8C%97/) is written in Chinese, but you can follow the pics:
https://hanbaobao2005.wordpress.com/2016/06/07/python%E5%A4%9A%E7%89%88%E6%9C%AC-sublime-text-anaconda%E6%8C%87%E5%8C%97/

Answer (score 0):

Open a new file and write this:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Save the file as `Python3.sublime-build`, then change your Build System to Python3 and try to run your code again. Now, it should run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that the problem was with this line, "selector": "source.python". Once I changed it to "selector": "source.py", and re-open the python program file, it worked.